# Multiple virtual hosts on localhost for development

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, httpd.conf, xampp

I'm using Xampp (Apace 2.2.20) on mac os lion for development.  I have a number of CMS projects and i want to access them by going to cms1.localhost, cms2.localhost, cms3.localhost etc

Currently, with the setup I have below, everything goes to whatever is in the first virtual hosts directive ie (/Applications/XAMPP/migration/trunk).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.  I can't think what else to do in terms of debug etc so that help would be useful too.  Thanks a lot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/migration/trunk"
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName rix.localhost
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/projects/giving"
</Virtualhost>
```

In /etc/hosts I have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 rix.localhost
```

Comment: Where is that VHost file? It's possible that it's not the one being read. I know that seems dumb, but I've seen people get bitten by that fish before ;)

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes, try swapping the VirtualHost declarations, confirm that the file is the correct one, and restart Apache.

They're all simple things, but best to check there first.